# How to process while scrapy crawling data from an url which one's data controlled by another url

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Recently I'm researching crawling,and I choose `dataurl`,I can easily get the data with scrapy.But it is always responsing English data.

For getting Chinese data,I found  what `dataurl` responses depends on what   country language of  `urlControllLangContentByServerSide` is with parameter  `&plang=1`. I even append `&plang=3`  or formdata `{plang:3}`for `dataurl`,but that doesn't work

In short,`urlControllLangContentByServerSide` should be visited first ,if i want to get the Chinese data of `dataurl`,this has been proved by  many tests on postman,and I don't know how to deal with this  in code.

Thank you for your time for reading and thinking.

```
 def start_requests(self):
     urlControllLangContentByServerSide='http://messefrankfurt.kenti-creative.com/index.php?moduleId=129&pageName=list2&pId=14&plang=3'
     dataurl='http://messefrankfurt.kenti-creative.com/modules/exhibitor/ajax/more2.php?moduleId=129&pageName=list2&pId=14&yId=0&hId=0&uId=-2&cId=undefined&aId=-1&fId=0&plang=3'
    # I even append &plang=3 for dataurl,But that doesn't work 
     for  s in range(5):
         time.sleep(.5)  #im trying to visit this url many times to tell server what  
         #language should be used!  maybe that server uses session to controll language data.
         yield scrapy.Request(urlControllLangContentByServerSide,callback=self.parse_m,method='POST')

     for  i in range(5):
         form_data={"page":"%s" % i}
         self.current_index=i
         yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse,
                             method='POST', formdata=form_data)
     print(self.wrongs)
 def  parse_m(self,response):
     with open('mother%s.html'% random.randint(3,90) ,'wb') as f:
         f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you need to visit `urlControllLangContentByServerSide` first and sequentially the dataurl, you can since bounce your request from the parse_m method like this:

```
 def start_requests(self):
     urlControllLangContentByServerSide='http://messefrankfurt.kenti-creative.com/index.php?moduleId=129&pageName=list2&pId=14&plang=3'
    # I even append &plang=3 for dataurl,But that doesn't work 
     for  s in range(5):
         time.sleep(.5)  #im trying to visit this url many times to tell server what  
         #language should be used!  maybe that server uses session to controll language data.
         yield scrapy.Request(urlControllLangContentByServerSide,callback=self.parse_m,method='POST')

     print(self.wrongs)

 def  parse_m(self,response):
     dataurl='http://messefrankfurt.kenti-creative.com/modules/exhibitor/ajax/more2.php?moduleId=129&pageName=list2&pId=14&yId=0&hId=0&uId=-2&cId=undefined&aId=-1&fId=0&plang=3'
     with open('mother%s.html'% random.randint(3,90) ,'wb') as f:
         f.write(response.body)
     form_data={"page":"%s" % i}
     self.current_index=i
     yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse,
                             method='POST', formdata=form_data)

 def  parse(self,response):
    pass #Parse the response of dataurl
```

In the case you need to pass data between requests you can use the meta attribute. See [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scrapy/scrapy_requests_and_responses.htm) for more information and an example on how to use meta attribute.

Comment: thanks bro, really easy solution. but i even had not tried that way.

Comment: actually , i  used   google chrome console  shell to crawl the data instead of scrapy.